# Targeting friends of a specific user with Facebook Marketing API

Tags: advertising, facebook, marketing, facebook-graph

Our website provide a service that is mainly targeting friends of our users. We had this great idea of using the [`friends_of_connection`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs) setting to show custom ads to friends per user. In other words, friends of user#1 should receive ad#1 and friends of user#2 should receive ad#2 etc.

But it seems that this option does not work as we expected at first. As it seems to allow only pages or applications ids, not user ids to target their friends.

I am putting this here to see if this is still possible to achieve through the Facebook Marketing API either with the above option or another option. Have you been able to achieve something similar to this before?